# RavenDB deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 app that I've developed which uses RavenDB Embedded as an integrated backing store for data, I used [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=787) tutorial as a basis for getting started creating an MVC app with RavenDB Embedded.  I've been able to run it fine on my development PC, but when it came time to deploy it on our Windows Server 2003 web server running IIS6 it threw the following error:

> Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentFileAccessDeniedException: Cannot
>   access file, the file is locked or in use
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [EsentFileAccessDeniedException: Cannot access file, the file is
>   locked or in use]    Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err)
>   in
>   C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:2736
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator
>   uuidGenerator) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:207
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Could not open transactional storage:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\App_Data\Database\RavenDB\Data]
>   Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator
>   uuidGenerator) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:222
>   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration
>   configuration) in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:185
>   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.InitializeInternal() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Embedded\EmbeddableDocumentStore.cs:143
>   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize() in
>   c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentStore.cs:496
>   MyApp.CompositionRoot.CreateControllerFactory() in
>   ...\MyApp\CompositionRoot.cs:36    MyApp.CompositionRoot..ctor() in
>   ..\MyApp\CompositionRoot.cs:17
>   MyApp.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in ...MyApp\Global.asax.cs:38
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not open transactional storage:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\App_Data\Database\RavenDB\Data]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +3985477
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +325
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +407
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +375
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not open transactional storage:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\App_Data\Database\RavenDB\Data]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11524352
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +141    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4782309

The source of the error in the referenced CompositionRoot.cs class is when the initialization of the Embeddable Document Store.

```
private static IControllerFactory CreateControllerFactory()
{
    var cacheRepository = new EmbeddableDocumentStore();
    cacheRepository.ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB";

    #if DEBUG
        cacheRepository.UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true;
    #endif

    Raven.Database.Server.NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
    cacheRepository.Initialize(); //Source of Error
    var controllerFactory = new TDRControllerFactory(cacheRepository);
    return controllerFactory;
}
```

Why is this only happening on the web server and not on my development PC?  I'm not sure what the exact cause might be.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sounds like a classic permissions issue running under IIS. No familiar with RavenDB embedded, but I would move it outside of \webroot and give the IIS user priveleges to that path.

Comment: is RavenDB already running either as a service or from the command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This turned out to be a permissions issue, I gave the IIS_IUSRS group modify and write permissions on the root of my application's folder and that gave it the permissions it needed to initialize the database properly.  There's probably a specific folder within the root that it needs modify/write access to (in my case, probably the App_Data folder, since that's where I'm instantiating my instance of RavenDB). I'll have to test as I wouldn't want any user to have modify/write rights to the entire application folder.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that your `CreateControllerFactory` will run only once, even in the face of concurrent requests at app startup.

Comment: Thanks Ayende, the error turned out to be a permissions issue.  I gave modify and write access of the root folder of my application to the IIS_IUSRS group and that allowed the database to initialize properly.  I will keep your answer in mind as well in case the issue ever comes up again.  Fantastic work on RavenDB, this is our first venture into a non-relational database, so we're anxious to see how it works.